# in python, how to swap indexes within a list of list of lists

Tags: python, list, swap

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Output should be:

```
b = [[2,1], [4,3], [6,5]]
```

How do I achieve the expected outcome? Tried searching for similar posts, but the codes swap 'lists' not within a 'list' of 'list of lists'.

Comment: `[i[::-1] for i in a]`

Comment: _Tried searching for similar posts, but the codes swap 'lists' not within a 'list' of 'list of lists'._ Then all you need to do is apply whatever method you found to each sublist, right? What do you mean by _swap indexes_?

Comment: It worked! Just so I do not waste other's time, can someone suggest what phrase I could have searched in google or in stackoverflow that would have fetched me such a simple one line code

Comment: Another way to express it but not a generic solution is `[[y,x] for x,y in a]`.

Comment: Code given by accdias also worked!

Comment: Presquevu's is a better solution because it will work with lists of any length. On mine I just tried to be didactic.

Comment: In case you don't actually need it as a new list: `for s in a: s.reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Our three suggestions from the comments, benchmarked:

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> setup = 'a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]; b = [[2,1], [4,3], [6,5]]'

>>> min(repeat('[i[::-1] for i in a]', setup))
0.7484351999999959

>>> min(repeat('[[y,x] for x,y in a]', setup))
0.553510899999992

>>> min(repeat('for s in a: s.reverse()', setup))
0.30734420000000284
```

Comment: There's also `reversed()`, eh.

Comment: @AMC Yeah, but only gives you an iterator, not a list, and it's already longer...

Comment: @AMC Also, I just measured `[reversed(i) for i in a]` and that's already 0.94 seconds, when it pretty much hasn't done anything yet (since it's only an iterator).